# How to Send GPS Coordinates to Another Class

Tags: java, android, class, gps

I'm working on organizing my application and I need some help sending the GPS coordiates to another class that sends them to a database. When the send button in the Main activity is pressed, it starts an intent that begins the LocationActivity. From there, I'd like to send the GPS coordinates to the SendActivity which sends them to a database (through a PHP program). How do I send the coordinates to SendActivity? I comment a section where I tried but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

LocationActivity.java:

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity{

    private LocationManager locManager;
    private LocationListener locListener;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startLocation();
    }

    private void startLocation()
    {   
        //get a reference to the LocationManager
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //checked to receive updates from the position
        locListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                SendActivity.send(location); //What to do here?
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
                //labelState.setText("Provider OFF");
            }
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
                //labelState.setText("Provider ON ");
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
                //Log.i("", "Provider Status: " + status);
            }
        };

        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
    }
}
```

SendActivity.java:

```
public class SendActivity extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    void send(Location loc)
    {
        Log.i("", String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude() + " - " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude())));
         String lat = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()); 
         String lon = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());

        SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("PEOPLE_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String usr_id2 = shared.getString("USR_ID", "none");

        if (lat != "0" && lon != "0")   
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/test/example.php");
         try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat)); 
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", lon));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", usr_id2));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
         } 
         catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         } 
         catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing doesn't make sense. Plz consider just saving in database the "regular" way and not through another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create an Activity to get LatLong..
Following is the class to get LatLong :

```
class UpdateGeoLocation {
    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;
    double lat, lng;
    Location location;
    Location returnlocation;
    Context context;

    public static String locationdetails = null;

    public UpdateGeoLocation(Context context) {
        this.context = context;     
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        returnlocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }

    public Location getLocation(Location location) {

        if (location != null) {
            Log.d("one", "IF getLocation :: " + location);
            returnlocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            returnlocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

        } else {
            try {
                listenForLocation(provider);
            } catch (NullPointerException nullPointerException) {
                nullPointerException.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return returnlocation;

    }

    private void listenForLocation(String providerName) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(providerName, 0, 0,
                locationListener);
        if (location != null) {
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();
            getLocation(location);
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(context, "location null",
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            returnlocation.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            returnlocation.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

}


Following is the Activity where I used above class to get LatLong :

Location location = null;

OnCreate() :

try {
    Looper.prepare();
    if (null != (location = requestForLocation())) {
        if (null != location) {
            Log.d("one", "Location :: " + location.getLatitude());
            Log.d("one", "Location  LATLONG :: " + location.getLongitude());

                        //Use intent or bundle here to send LatLong to other activities..


        } else {
            Log.d("one", "Location not found:: ");

        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} 


private Location requestForLocation() {
    return new UpdateGeoLocation(MonsterLoginActivity.this)
    .getLocation(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really intend for SendActivity to be an entirely new activity, or do you just want a class to implement a Send function? If its the latter you can just make it a regular class and not make it an activity.

If you want SendActivity to be a new activity (with a new activity screen), you would launch it with a new intent, and add the gps coordinates to the intent bundle.

Something like

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
   //SendActivity.send(location); //What to do here?
   Intent i = new Intent(this, SendActivity.class);
   float lat = ... //calculate lat and lon here
   float lon = ...
   i.putExtra("latitude", lat);
   i.putExtra("longitude", lon);
   this.startActivity(i);
}
```

In SendActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    float lat = getIntent().getFloatExtra("latitude");
    float lon = getIntent().getFloatExtra("longitude");
}
```

But it doesn't make sense I think to just call a function inside another activity.

Comment: So how would I make a class for this instead? I'm trying to now, but I'm not sure how I begin the startLocation() from the main activity.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to send location between classes.

1) send through Broadcast reciever.

2) save it in some variable/preferences and read it from another activity.

3) implement a Handler and pass through Message/send message.

4) pass through  intents/put extra.

and lots of other ways.